# Hibernate query returning wrong date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, simpledateformat

When i retrieve a date from a mysql table it always return the date 1 day before, the date format is yyyy-MM-dd, so if i have 2018-10-17 when i print the result it comes as 2018-10-16. If i use the command line to check the dates, they are correct.
This is the method inside the Dao class that retrieves the dates:

```
public List<LocalDate> getDates(String username){
    List<LocalDate> dates;
    Query query = manager.createQuery("select date from Calendar where username =:username");
    query.setParameter("username",username);
    dates = query.getResultList();
    return dates;
}
```

When I print the list all the dates are printed 1 day before as I was on my sql.

This is how I get the dates on the servlet and use hibernate to store the dates on mysql.

```
String dateString = request.getParameter("date");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate dataInicial = LocalDate.parse(dataInicialString, formatter);
```

The Datatype that im using in mysql is DATE.
Then I user hibernate to do the rest for me, if you need any piece of code that I didin't provide please ask me. 
Thx in advance.

Sorry for bad english!

Comment: The classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and poorly designed. A newer Hibernate should be able to get you the date as `LocalDate` from the database, which I warmly recommend. It solves your problem since a `LocalDate` has got neither time of day nor time zone. As an extra bonus `LocalDate` and the other classes from java.time are so much nicer to work with. [java,time is the modern Java date and time API.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: If you can't change the server's timezone settings, you can try changing Hibernate's settings as described by one of it's maintainers https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/

Comment: @OleV.V. i made some changes to the code and updated the question/post, i think that should be it, but it still remains the same problem, i checked the date before storing it in mysql ant it was the date that i wnated, i used the command line to select the dates in mysql and there they were correct too, im using the Datatype in mysql as DATE, should i change it? or is it still some code errors to fix? thx for your time and answer. Sorry for bad english if any mistakes were made

Comment: Sorry that it didn’t help as expected. I’m afraid I’m out of suggestions, but is you tell us the datatype in MySQL, someone may more easily help you?

Comment: The Datatype is DATE, when i use the command line to check the dates they are as supposed, but when i do the HQL query to retrive the dates they return 1 day before they are in the database. 
Thx for you time @OleV.V.

Comment: It’s weird. I still suspect a time zone issue, but I certainly hadn’t expected it to affect dates without time of day and without time zone.

Comment: @OleV.V. i found what needed to be done, i changed the HQL query, i dont know exactly why but when i do "Query query = manager.createQuery("select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') from Calendar where username =:username");" it works!!!! And thx for the LocalDate advice, it is nicer to work with!

Answer (score 1):

i found what needed to be done, i changed the HQL query, i dont know exactly why but when i do

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') from Calendar where username =:username");
```

it works!!!!

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same that u had, but in my case i have to retrieve the whole row instead of only date in select query, What should i do??? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I once had this issue and the reason resided in the default time zone of my MySQL configuration. So, first check out the time zone you are using with the following query.

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

If it is not the desired time zone, try going into your MySQL configuration file and add the following line.

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone = '00:00'
```

Remember to set it to the desired time zone. You will need to restart your MySQL for the change to take place. This change will be permanent.

Comment: SELECT @@global.time_zone return SYSTEM, what to do??